# I can't install anything from software center

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I try to hit install this shows up:

> Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
>   apt transaction returned result exit-failed

What should I do? Please help...

Comment: answered in [same questions I asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943267/cant-install-via-ubuntu-software-apt-transaction-returned-result-exit-failed/943321?noredirect=1#comment1498242_943321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943267/cant-install-via-ubuntu-software-apt-transaction-returned-result-exit-failed) thread the problem is that Ubuntu is downloading from the wrong server. To fix this hit the windows key and type "software & updates" (I know my instructions are slightly different. Since Ubuntu has switched desktops in 17.10 the steps it originally gives may not get you to the right menu. I haven't confirmed this since I'm sticking with the old layout).

Then go ahead and select the "Ubuntu Software" tab. Now click the drop-down menu labelled "Download from" and select "Other..." and click "select best server". Wait a bit and select "choose server".

Enter your login password and press enter. Wait for it to do it's thing. When it's done select "close" and then "reload" on the pop-up. If it asks for you password again, enter it. Wait. When it closes you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to update software center. Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gnome-software` and see if that fixes it. I believe there was a version of gnome-software that is shipped with Ubuntu that would cause it not to start (this was fixed in a update).

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the software centre is already the newest version according to the output of those commands.

Comment: Try a full update: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`