# Cant install via Ubuntu Software- "apt transaction returned result exit-failed"

Tags: software-installation, 17.04

I'm using 17.04 ( Clean Install ), and as far as I remember, every try to install any sofware- it fails with that error code.

I tried `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and problem persists.

any idea why?
[image: snapshot from screen]

edit:
Using software Updater gave this result :
[image]

edit : output of update

```
guy@LG-LAPTOP:~$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for guy: 
Ign:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease              
Ign:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease            
Err:4 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release                        
  503  Service Unavailable
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]     
Err:6 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release                
  503  Service Unavailable
Get:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease [10.2 kB]            
Err:8 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release              
  503  Service Unavailable
Get:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty/partner Sources [1,416 B]      
Get:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty/partner amd64 Packages [1,616 B]
Get:11 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty/partner i386 Packages [1,612 B]
Get:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty/partner Translation-en [708 B]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11.7 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [9,219 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [14.4 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [31.0 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                         
E: The repository 'http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
guy@LG-LAPTOP:~$
```

output of apt get

```
guy@LG-LAPTOP:~$ sudo apt-get install putty
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  putty-tools
Suggested packages:
  putty-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  putty putty-tools
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 661 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,713 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 putty-tools amd64 0.67-3
  503  Service Unavailable
Err:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 putty amd64 0.67-3
  503  Service Unavailable
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/putty/putty-tools_0.67-3_amd64.deb  503  Service Unavailable
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/putty/putty_0.67-3_amd64.deb  503  Service Unavailable
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
guy@LG-LAPTOP:~$
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're having problems with your software sources servers.  Change it from the Software Sources app.  You can get to it by:

- (Click) the **Gear Icon** at the top left
- **System Settings**
- **Software & Updates**
- (click the tab) **Ubuntu Software**
- Choose a different server from the **Download Dropdown**

You'll get the best server if you choose **Other**, then click **Select Best Server**.  On that option, the system will run tests and match you with a mirror server with the best performance for your location.

Comment: Works like a charm ( after setting server to **Main Server**)

Comment: Glad it worked.  Thanks for the acknowledgment.